# Recovering ignored files deleted by Git when checking out prior commits

Tags: git

Did a commit, then pushed to the repository.  Have a couple of files that git ignores, but that is okay, I have a local copy, right?  Learned how I could check out past versions.  Great!  Loved it!  Then tried to go back, but my ignored versions are gone!  I don't show it below, but believe me they are gone.  How do I recover them?  If not possible, what should I read to prevent this from ever happening again?

```
 1014  git status
 1015  git checkout 084322b33
 ...
 1040  git checkout 32484241e
 1043  git status
 1044  git reset --hard origin/master
 1045  git fetch origin
 1042  git reset --hard origin/master
 1047  git pull origin master
 1048  git status
```

Comment: If you use a proper IDE like IntelliJ/Webstorm or Netbeans, you should have a local history which you can restore/revert to for situations like this.

Comment: @AlienWebguy  Well, as my dad used to say, if a dog didn't stop to take a poop (PS.  he didn't say "poop"), he would have caught the rabbit.  I thank you for your commit, but my condition still remains.

Comment: As you said you checked out a commit... That means if you do git status , you should be in a "DETACHED STATE " .... Check if that is the case and then i can guide you further

Comment: @cafebabe1991  Yes I am.  `git status
HEAD detached at 9648426
nothing to commit, working directory clean`.  Just used `git checkout master`, and are back on the master, however, the ignored files are still gone.

Comment: Ignore files are gone.... You mean the files that were pushed and you were OK with it ? Those files you are talking about ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991  A couple of files were ignored using `.gitignore`.  I then added all files unless ignored by `.gitignore` and pushed.  I then checked out some earlier commits.  When going back to the master, those ignored files were no longer existed.

Comment: So the files that were ignored would then have been listed in untracked and they have disappeared as you said that means ... They have been deleted by someone not bybgit as they were untracked..

Comment: @cafebabe1991  I was almost certain they were there, I checkout an older commit, and then they were gone.  That being said, I am sure you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned that you checked out a commit and then you saw that the files that were ignored were gone now...

This happened NOT because of git but because of someone deleting it manually .

**Reason**

This is because the files were untracked and hence  git  was not bothered about them and hence could not be the one who deleted it.

**Avoidance**

- Access control can be one way. Make sure the right user has the right permissions for the file/directory.
- Create a backup if you need .
- Just be careful
- track the untracked files first and then stash them so to save them..

Or
Since git 1.7.7 you can save the untracked files in stash by using

```
git stash -u
```

And [read this article](http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/) this article before you use this command.